# JSON error when using mongoimport utility

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So, i am importing the data from the json file to the mongodb using mongoimport utility using the following command:

```
mongoimport --db city --collection inspections ./city_inspections.json #mongo import utility
```

where the json data is like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"56d61033a378eccde8a8354f"},"id":"10021-2015-ENFO","certificate_number":9278806,"business_name":"ATLIXCO DELI GROCERY INC.","date":"Feb 20 2015","result":"No Violation Issued","sector":"Cigarette Retail Dealer - 127","address":{"city":"RIDGEWOOD","zip":11385,"street":"MENAHAN ST","number":1712}}
```

Now, when entering the command, i am getting the error:
[image: errorinmongodb]

Can anyone help me on how to resolve the error.

Comment: Try to use `{ "$numberInt":"9278806"}` instead of plain number. And you should **never** store date values as string, use proper `Date` object, i.e. `{"$date": {"$numberLong": "<millis>"}}` - see [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson-data-types-and-associated-representations)

Comment: Does your json file has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: I imported your JSON (as it is) into a MongoDB collection without any errors. I was running on MongoDB v4.2 on Windows OS. It could be a problem with a specific JSON document _or_ something else. How many documents are you importing, and they in an array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of  mongoimport --version ?

What's your version of MongoDB that you're trying to import to?

I made a json file with 2 records (copied your record twice and changed the _id on one of them) and used your mongoimport statement and got no errors.

Answer (score 0):

The last bit that you have is just a comment, and you dont have to put it in the script... the "#mongo import utility"